# How to run standalone files created by anylogic in matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, jar, anylogic

I have been training on AnyLogic software, but I am totally new to this.
I have a model which is already build and I now want to run this model in MATLAB.
The solution I have tried to do I created a standalone file for my model which gave a bunch of files which had libraries, bat files .jar file and couple of text files. You can go through this [link](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/running/export-java-application.html#exporting-models-to-java-application) for which files are created.

I am trying to find a complete process of doing this but all I found were to add path to environment variables but not complete steps so not able to understand what to do before or after that.

Can somebody give a simple process to follow all the steps which would guide me to run the model?